# Pass array to a function as a pointer and value

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

What is the deference between passing array this way:

```c
static char arr[N];

void func(void *buf, size_t size) {
    // ...
}

int main(void) {
    func(arr, N);

    // ...
}
```

And this way:

```c
// ...

int main(void) {
    func(&arr, N);

    // ...
}
```

Is there any deference in those listings? It seems that the 2nd version passes an array as `void **`, but is it really so?

Comment: Due to [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471), `func(arr, N);` is equivalent to `func(&arr[0], N);`, i.e. you are passing a pointer to the first element of the array. In the second example, you are passing a pointer to the entire array, not to a single element. In C, both are possible, but it is generally easier to work with pointers to the first element of the array, instead of pointers to an entire array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is correct and the second is wrong or at least very questionable.

`arr` when used in an expression or passed to a function, gets adjusted to a pointer to the first element. So it turns equivalent to `char*`.

In the second example, `&arr` is one of the few exceptions to this "array decay" rule. Instead of a pointer to the first element, we get a pointer to the whole array, type `char(*)[N]`. This type is not compatible with `char*`, so if you would attempt to cast the `void* buf` to a `char*` inside the function, the second example causes a subtle bug.

The reason why the second example compiles at all is because `void*` (and only that type, not `void**`) is a special pointer type that can be converted to/from any other pointer to object. Should you change the function to

```
void func(char *buf, size_t size)
```

Then `func(&arr, N);` gives the expected compiler diagnostic "passing argument 1 of 'func' from incompatible pointer type".

Now as it happens, if you write the function like this

```
void func(void *buf, size_t size) {
    char* ptr = buf;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
      printf("%c ", ch[i]);
    }
}
```

It will most likely work for either version, because the address of the first item (`char*`) is the same as the address of the array (`char(*)[N]`). Also, C's peculiar type system allows us to access a memory location of some type through an array or struct of items of that same type ("the strict aliasing rule").

Best practices:

- Use the first version.
- Avoid the use of `void*` when possible, since they are type unsafe.
- Be as explicit with types as you can and don't rely on implicit type conversions.